# nested dependency of npm package broke everything

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, metalsmith

I've picked up a project that I didn't touch for more than a month and when trying to deploy I found the build was failing. I can replicate the error locally.
The project worked fine a month ago, no (direct) dependencies have been updated since then.

**My simple question is**: *is there any way to narrow down who's the culprit of this mess via NPM?*

A bit more information:
The project uses Gulp 4 and Metalsmith.
It also used Node lts/carbon until I switched to Node 6 for deployment reasons.

I've managed to narrow down the error to a specific Metalsmith plugin although this plugin on its own has not been updated at all recently.

Reverting to a previous commit before any previous changes to the `package.json` file (i.e. almost 2 months ago) won't change anything and the problem will be still there.

I've opened a [ticket against metalsmith-tags](https://github.com/totocaster/metalsmith-tags/issues/53) with details around that if you want to dig further into this.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: for the specific question, no. Even if I found where the problem was originating from, I used a completely different way to narrow it down, and I really wish there was a way to narrow down nested dependencies changes across time. So far no luck.